# Testing a Node Module with Intern Js- Can't resolve 'require'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, javascript-framework, intern

I am trying to test a simple node Module with intern.The module is an AMD module.  I am running into a couple of issues

1. If the module is defined as below, I get the error "moduleName" has
   no method 'map' "

   `define('moduleName',[]function(require){   var r= require('request');
   })`
2. If the module is defined as below without a moduleName, I see this
       error "undefined is not a function" - I guess its not able to resolve 'require'

   `define([]function(require){   var r= require('request'); })`

Here is how my Test Looks

```
define([
'intern!object',
'intern/chai!assert',
'/src/api/nameApi'
], function (registerSuite, assert,nameApi) {
    registerSuite({
    name: 'GetName Test',
    getName: function () {
        var nameFromApi = nameApi.getName();
        assert( nameFromApi!= null,'name is not null');
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Providing an explicit module ID as the first argument to `define` destroys module portability and shouldn’t be done. It is not currently supported by the loader used by the master branch because it is such a bad idea. It *is* supported by the geezer branch, but again, I strongly advise you to never use this pattern.

The second module definition you have provided is just wrong; you need to put `'require'` in your dependencies array if you expect to load the special require function. You also can’t use a variable to pass a module ID to the `require` function if you are expecting it to be pre-loaded as a dependency. So, it should look like this:

```js
define(['require', 'foo'], function (require) {
    var foo = require('foo');
});
```

or, using the CommonJS compatibility wrapper syntax, where `require` is implicitly provided:

```js
define(function (require) {
    var r = require('foo');
});
```

EDIT: Also, now that you have added the test module: within your test’s `define`, '/src/api/nameApi' is not a valid [AMD module identifier](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD#module-id-format-).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was a typo for the request, changed in the question now. I tried with `['require']` in the dependencies, But it can't load the 'request' module.  Do I have to specify the `request` module in the `test/intern.js`  in `loader`. If so how to load all the modules in node_modules?

`Attempt to require unloaded module request
    at contextRequire (/Users/userId/Documents/gitRepos/MyProject/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:255:12)`

Comment: The answer is exactly the same. Your define call is wrong, missing the dependencies you are trying to load. Please read http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules/ and/or http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep to learn how AMD dependencies work.

Comment: Here is how my module definition looks, Don't think there is nothing wrong  with this. `define(function (require) {
    var foo = require('request');
});`

if this definition is right how do I make sure the 'request' and other npm_modules are loaded. The application is able to load the 'request' module, but not the test. So how can I ensure the tests load all the modules that the application loads

Comment: If you are trying to load Node.js modules then please read [testing non-AMD code](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests#commonjs-code) in the wiki.